# Selecting the Id's that have the same EmailAddress column value

Tags: sql, sql-server

What I need:

I am looking for a solution that can give me all the Employee Id's that have the same EmailAddress Column (the filter needs to be by EmailAddress).
I want to know what are the Id's correspondent to the duplicated Email Addresses and retrieve that information.

Table Employee:

```
Id | PlNumber | EmailAddress | EmployeeBeginingDate | EmployedEndDate | Name UserId(FK) | CreatedBy | CreatedOn
```

---

```
SELECT a.Id,a.EmailAddress
FROM Employee a
INNER JOIN (SELECT 
                Employee.Id as EmployeeId,
                Employee.EmailAddress as EmailAddress,                
            FROM Employee
            GROUP BY Employee.Id,Employee.EmailAddress
            HAVING count(Employee.EmailAddress) > 1
                ) b
ON a.Id= b.EmployeeId  
ORDER BY a.Id
```

I am always getting an error:

> the multi-part identifier could not be bound.

I know why the error is happening but I couldn't solve this.

UPDATE: After a few changes the query is returning 0 rows but I know it should return at least 3 rows that I have duplicate values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below query as you have an aliased table `Employee` as `a`. So in place of Employee, you have to use `a`.

```
SELECT a.Id, a.EmailAddress
FROM Employee a
INNER JOIN (SELECT                    
                Employee.EmailAddress as EmailAddress                
            FROM Employee
            GROUP BY Employee.EmailAddress
            HAVING count(Employee.EmailAddress) > 1
                ) b
ON a.EmailAddress = b.EmailAddress
ORDER BY a.Id
```

Live [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=04d573d25e0ee5f7ea3d9c678a3b8fa9) demo.

Comment: now it says incorrect syntax near the keyword 'From'

Comment: @JoãoEs Please check now there was an extra comma in typo which I have corrected. Initially, the alias table error was also there.

Comment: ok, thank you for that just noticed it, but the query is returning no rows and there are 3 rows that it should retrieve , if i remove in the subquery the employee.Id then i will get my emails that are duplicated SELECT 
                
                Employee.EmailAddress as EmailAddress                
            FROM Employee
            GROUP BY Employee.EmailAddress
            HAVING count(Employee.EmailAddress) > 1

Comment: @JoãoEs It is because you have to remove Employee.Id as EmployeeId from the inner query please check now I have updated the query.

Comment: @JoãoEs For every employee, the Id is different so you could not group based on the Ids.

Comment: in that case i can't do that join ON a.Id = b.EmployeeId since there won't be an EmployeeId

Comment: yes, i guess you are right but how can i retrieve this information that i need then? i need to know the Employees associated with the same Email Address

Comment: @JoãoEs You can join based on the email address as I have done and select another column also like Id, Name, etc.

Comment: @JoãoEs Thank you message is not suggested by SO bu you can accept the answer to appreciate see how at the link https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the ids are different on each row, I would go for `exists`:

```
SELECT e.Id, e.EmailAddress
FROM Employee e
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM Employee e2
              WHERE e2.EmailAddress = e.EmailAddress AND
                    e2.Id <> e.Id
             )
ORDER BY e.EmailAddress;
```

Or, if you want to know the number of matches, use window functions:

```
SELECT e.Id, e.EmailAddress, cnt
FROM (SELECT e.*, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY e.EmailAddress) as cnt
      FROM Employee e
     ) e
WHERE cnt >= 2;
```